# Oracle XMLTABLE namespace issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, namespaces, xmltype, xmltable

I am trying to get envelope_id as 80621b17-97a8-926d945b602a from the below XML through this script, but nothing comes out. Can any one have any idea ?

```
SELECT b.EnvelopeID
FROM   sample_xml a,
       XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd_k",
                              'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "xsi",
                              'http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0' AS "k"),
       '/xsd_k:DocuSignEnvelopeInformation/xsd_k:EnvelopeStatus' PASSING a.xml
                       COLUMNS EnvelopeID        VARCHAR2(200)   PATH 'EnvelopeID')b;
```

My sample xml is :

```
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docgign.net/API/3.0">
  <EnvelopeStatus>
    <EnvelopeID>80621b17-97a8-926d945b602a</EnvelopeID>
   </EnvelopeStatus>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Thanks Andrej! I didn't get any errors, simply not displaying anything. But the answer from Mottot below works fine. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the default namespace. Just say 'default' :). And look to be the same as in your XML document:

```
SELECT b.EnvelopeID
FROM   (SELECT xmltype ('
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docgign.net/API/3.0">
  <EnvelopeStatus>
    <EnvelopeID>80621b17-97a8-926d945b602a</EnvelopeID>
   </EnvelopeStatus>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>') AS xml FROM DUAL) a,
       XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.docgign.net/API/3.0'),
       '/DocuSignEnvelopeInformation/EnvelopeStatus' PASSING a.xml
                       COLUMNS EnvelopeID        VARCHAR2(200)   PATH 'EnvelopeID')b;
```

We can also repair your variant. First you have 'docgign' instead of 'docusign' in the xml document. Repair one of the both. Than change '/xsd_k:DocuSignEnvelopeInformation/xsd_k:EnvelopeStatus' with '/k:DocuSignEnvelopeInformation/k:EnvelopeStatus', because this is the default namespace and at last change 'EnvelopeID' with 'k:EnvelopeID' :

```
SELECT EnvelopeID
FROM   (SELECT xmltype ('
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
  <EnvelopeStatus>
    <EnvelopeID>80621b17-97a8-926d945b602a</EnvelopeID>
   </EnvelopeStatus>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>') AS xml FROM DUAL) a,
       XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd_k",
                              'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "xsi",
                              'http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0' AS "k"),
       '/k:DocuSignEnvelopeInformation/k:EnvelopeStatus' PASSING a.xml
                       COLUMNS EnvelopeID        VARCHAR2(200)   PATH 'k:EnvelopeID')b;
```

See [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx)(search for Default Namespace)

> When a default namespace declaration is used on an element, all
>   unqualified element names within its scope are automatically
>   associated with the specified namespace identifier.

That is the reason because DocuSignEnvelopeInformation and all other nodes under this have the namespace xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0". If this namespace was not defined, the nodes would be without namespace and you wouldn't need to use namespace in xmltable.

Comment: Thanks much Mottor! It worked now. Apart from the spelling mistake ( 'docgign' instead of 'docusign' ) here,  I was wondering that I am not sure why I should not use xsd_k. When I should use default one and when I should use the other ones? Thanks in advance

Comment: @xml_programmer The default namespace under which are all nodes (because they do not use namespace name and there is namespace on the root node) is the namespace without name xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0". All other have names "xsi","xsd". And when the node should under namespace with name, the name should be used like <xsi:DocuS....>. What for macaron I wrote? :)